# C11 Bus error:10

Tags: c

I am very new  in C, I am currently just trying to read a file with the contents "6" and nothing else. Whenever I run the file, I get: Bus Error:10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char input(void);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{


    input();

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

char input(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *score;

    fp = fopen("data.bin", "rt");


    fscanf(fp,"%s", score);

    printf("%s", score);

    fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: `score` doesn't point to anything but you try to read into the memory pointed to by it with `fscanf`.

Comment: There are good reasons `score` is called a **pointer** and not _array_. It would be quite useless to have two different types behave the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void input(void);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    input();
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void input(void) {
    char buffer[10];
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr = fopen("data.bin","rb");  // r for read, b for binary
    fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, ptr); // read 10 bytes to our buffer
    printf("%s", buffer);

    fclose(ptr);
}
```

Output:

> 6

and for more, read this: [Read/Write to binary files in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598572/read-write-to-binary-files-in-c).