# How to print the output of BF_ecb_encrypt to a file

Tags: c, openssl, blowfish

the problem is that when I put the output in the file there must be any character which is not write well because then try decrypting then halfway through the process reaches a point where everything goes wrong, a part is decypted good and some not. Hence i want to know how to print it well into the file.

I try to used fwrite and fread like in [Read/Write to binary files in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598572/read-write-to-binary-files-in-c) but it does not solved my problem

Comment: Your code example please?

Comment: Dont print it, write it, as the encryption can generate non-printable characters. So also `fread` it back, don't `fgets` it or so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read/Write to binary files in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598572/read-write-to-binary-files-in-c)

Comment: i dont know if that solve my problem, i going to check that