# How to write binary data file in C and plot it using gnuplot

Tags: c, binary, gnuplot, binaryfiles

I need some help.

I have two arrays (**x_val[]** and **y_val[]**) of data with the **x** and **y** values of some points in the plane, so that **(x,y)** is a point in the 2D space. I write the data following the next format:

[data_file.dat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmgkX.png)

Then I use GNUPLOT for drawing all the points:

**plot 'data_file.dat' u 1:2 w points**

The problem is that the size of the file is almost 1Gb and I need to generate almost 500 files. So I thought that it could be better to write the data in binary format and then plot it, but I don't know how to do either.

I would like to do it without changing the arrays **x_val[]** and **y_val[]** please.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a tall order.... Have a look at fopen. For example fopen( "data_file.data",  "wb");

Comment: I tried to do it using fopen( "data_file.data", "wb"); but I got the same result: a file with a ASCII like format ... Same format, same size

Comment: Ok, so you opened in binary mode with `"wb"` but how did you write the data? What kind of write statement did you use? Or did you use `printf` and end up writing it as a string? Use `open`, `read` and `write`, not `printf` and `scanf` which are for *formatted* data.

Comment: How to use `gnuplot` is a completely separate question. Here's a complementary link to the [`gnuplot` documentation](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.0/gnuplot.pdf).

Comment: I tried using fprinf("%lf \t %lf \n", x[ i ] , y[ i ] ) ... Because I saw fwrite() receibes just 1 pointer, but I have 2: x_val[ ] and y_val[ ]

Comment: Yeah, like I said, `fprintf` such as the one you did is going to format in ASCII, leaving you where you were before. You need `fwrite`. You're writing in binary. You do only get one pointer. So the simplest thing to do is write out `x[i]` and `y[i]` with separate `fwrite` calls. There's no rule that you need to use just one call to write out both coordinates. `fwrite(&x[i], 1, sizeof int, fp);` and `fwrite(&y[i], 1, sizeof int, fp);`.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. But how do I know it has two columns ? Or how do I plot it ?

Comment: You already know the data has two columns. Does your program have to figure out automatically that there are two coordinates? Are you supporting cases where there are more or less than 2 coordinates? To your second question, see the GNU plot documentation. Read more specifically, for example, [Gnuplot: binary general](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node103.html)

Comment: Ok. Thank you everybody!