# How can I write a number directly to an ofstream object?

Tags: c++, file, ofstream

When I open an ofstream object for a file I do:

```
std::ofstream outFile("myfile");
```

Then I want to want to some numbers to it, but the only method it has is the `::write()` method which takes a `const char*` and a size. So I could do:

```
int temp = 5;
outFile.write((const char*)&temp, sizeof(int));
```

There's also the input `operator <<`, but I don't want formatted input, I want it written as pure binary data. I was wondering if there's a way I can write directly like:

```
outFile.write(12, sizeof(int));
outFile.write(10, sizeof(int));
```

Instead of creating temporaries, or previously allocating an array. I'm thinking that the limitation is that the only value that I could put in the argument would be an RValue, and there doesn't seem there's a way of making an lvalue from an rvalue. I guess technically the rvalue lasts until the end of the line, so if there was the opposite of `std::move` it could work. Is it possible to do this writing numbers directly?

Comment: Your only options for writing unformatted data into a `std::ostream` are `write()`, and `put()`. That's it. Pick one.

Comment: I don't know your final application, but with information given, I probably choose to forget `ostream` to come back to plain old C like "(f)read, (f)write, (f)open" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598572/read-write-to-binary-files-in-c)

Comment: Just for context, I'm writing a bunch of buffers in, so ofstream::write() is fine, but what I wanted to do was to first put in a couple of header info, like size, so like insert a quick number or two at the beginning. Seemed way weird to first make a temporary first to do this, but oh well.

Comment: the way to make an lvalue from a rvalue is to create temporary: `auto lvalue = whatever_that_gives_you_a_rvalue;` ;)

Comment: Write (inline) function that writes `int` to `ofstream`. Problem solved.

Comment: Really it's no major problem, I was just wondering. Hmm, inline function? Lambda to the rescue?

Comment: @Garf365 how that would change requirement to take memory address of the variable?

Answer (score 3):

> So I could do:

You can do much better:

```
void writeInt( std::ostream &os, int i )
{
    os.write( reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i), sizeof( i ) );
}
```

then use it with rvalue or lvalue:

```
int i = 0;
writeInt( f, i );
writeInt( f, 5 );
writeInt( f, funtionReturnsInt() );
```

and you should do that anyway, as you may later want to change format you store/load data and this way you need to change it only once.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use a template which can write any primitive type:

```
template<typename T>
void write_item(std::ostream& os, const T& item) {
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&item), sizeof T);
}
```

Of course, you would probably want to put some constraints in there to avoid trying to do this with more complex types.

Answer (score 0):

Use "<<" operator . For example 
os << "123";
 Any string or object can be written to ostream without type casting.

Comment: This will format the string, and he wants the value represented in binary. So, `outFile << std::uint32_t{1}` will add a byte character representing 1, not a 4-byte value representing the system's understanding of 1.