# How to write CSV fields on a binary file?

Tags: c, file, csv, binary, fwrite

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct RegDados{

    char removido; //  deve ser inicializado com '-'
    int encadeamento; // deve ser inicializado com -1
    int nroInscricao; // nao aceita valores repetidos nem nulos
    double nota;
    char data[10]; // checar tipo
    char *cidade;
    int sizecid;
    char tagCampo4;
    char *nomeEscola;
    int sizesch;
    char tagCampo5;
}RegDados;

char * strtokEvenEmpty(char * s, const char * seps){

  static char * p = NULL;

  if (s != NULL)
    p = s;
  else if (p == NULL)
    return NULL;
  else
    s = p;

  while (*p) {
    if (strchr(seps, *p)) {
      *p++ = 0;
      return s;
    }
    p += 1;
  }
  return (*s) ? s : NULL;
}

const char * getfield(char* line, int num){

  const char * tok;

  for (tok = strtokEvenEmpty(line, ","); tok; tok = strtokEvenEmpty(NULL, ",\n")){
    if (!--num)
      return tok;
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main(){

  FILE * stream = fopen("trabalho1.csv.csv", "r+");
  FILE * ArqBin = fopen("test.bin","wb");
  RegDados regdados[5000];
  RegCab regcab;
  int i = 0;

  if(ArqBin == NULL) printf("Error");

  if (stream != NULL) {
    char line[1024];
    while (fgets(line, 1024, stream)) {  

      regdados[i].nroInscricao = atoi(getfield(line, 1));
      fwrite(&regdados[i].nroInscricao, sizeof(int), 1, ArqBin);

      regdados[i].nota =  atof(getfield(line, 2));
      fwrite(&regdados[i].nota, sizeof(double), 1, ArqBin); 

      strcpy(regdados[i].data, getfield(line, 3));                             
      fwrite(regdados[i].data, sizeof(char), 100, ArqBin);  

      regdados[i].cidade = getfield(line, 4);
      fwrite(regdados[i].cidade, sizeof(char), 100, ArqBin);

      regdados[i].nomeEscola = getfield(line, 5);
      fwrite(regdados[i].nomeEscola, sizeof(char), 100, ArqBin);  

      i++;
    }
    fclose(stream);
    fclose(ArqBin);
  }
  else{
    printf("Error");
  }
}
```

It already parses the fields of my file, but I can't write them on a binary file, because when I try to write, I get a lot of null fields, which doesn't happen when I don't write.

My CSV file looks like:

> nroInscricao,nota,data,cidade,nomeEscola
>
> 13893,353.9,26/11/2016,,FRANCISCO RIBEIRO CARRIL
>
> 13595,472.2,,Salgueiro,ALFREDO GUEDES
>
> 13894,614.4,28/11/2016,Recife,JOAO DE MOURA GUIMARAES
>
> 13880,403.2,29/11/2016,Fortaleza,ANTONIO DIAS PASCHOAL PR
>
> 13881,373.7,,Sao Jose da Tapera,DONIZETTI TAVARES DE LIM
>
> 13882,394.8,01/12/2016,Sao Bernardo do Cam,JUSTINO GOMES DE CASTRO

How can I write the each field on a binary file?

Comment: Unless I can understand what *"because it gets really weird."* means, I would suggest looking at  this possible duplicate [Read/Write to binary files in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598572/read-write-to-binary-files-in-c)

Comment: "get's really weird" is not a description. And I don't see you trying to write to a file anywhere in the code.

Comment: Where are your `#include`s?

Comment: Explain what you want, what difference the 'binary' file must have compared with the csv file ?

Comment: I dunno, but I get this error also when trying your code: `error: unknown type name ‘RegCab’; did you mean ‘RegDados’?`

Comment: `atof(getfield(line, 2))` : consider that `getfield(line, 2)` may return `NULL`.

Comment: `fwrite(regdados[i].data, sizeof(char), 100, ArqBin);`: you write 100 chars but the `data` is only 10 chars long.... and many other issues like that....

Comment: out of the fact it is normal you produce several 0 you use wrongly _getfield_ and you bypass fields, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I try to write, I get a lot of null fields, which doesn't happen when I don't write.

this is normal, the internal representation of number can contains several 0, for instance doing :

> ```
> fwrite(&regdados[i].nroInscricao, sizeof(int), 1, ArqBin);
> ```

if `regdados[i].nroInscricao` values 7 and your *int* are on 32bits that will write 3 times 0 and 1 time 7 (the order depends if you are on little/big endian).

Of course it is the same with the strings you write with a fixed size, so the padding characters can have any value including 0 (there are not initialized)

---

Your way to extract the fields with *getfield* is expensive because you extract the first token, then to get the second you have to bypass the first token, then to get the third you have to bypass the 2 first tokens etc.

A better way is to do `getfield(line, 1)` then `getfield(NULL, 1)` to get the second token, then to do `getfield(NULL, 1)` to get the third etc, so in fact the second argument is always 1 and you can remove its management

---

You try to open `trabalho1.csv.csv`, probably you want to open `trabalho1.csv`

---

In

> ```
> if(ArqBin == NULL) printf("Error");
>
> if (stream != NULL) {
> ```

it is not enough to print error, you must not continue, can be

```
if(ArqBin == NULL) 
  printf("Error");
else if (stream != NULL) {
```

or better replace

> ```
> FILE * stream = fopen("trabalho1.csv.csv", "r+");
> FILE * ArqBin = fopen("test.bin","wb");
> ...
> if(ArqBin == NULL) printf("Error");
>
> if (stream != NULL) {
>   ...
> }
> else{
>   printf("Error");
> }
> ```

by something like

```
FILE * stream = fopen("trabalho1.csv.csv", "r+");

if (stream == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "cannot open input file rabalho1.csv.csv");
  return -1;
}

FILE * ArqBin = fopen("test.bin","wb");

if (ArqBin == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "cannot open output file test.bin");
  fclose(stream); /* really useful if you do not stop execution */
  return -1;
}
...
```

Comment: "You have to call getfield all the times giving 1 as the second argument, so in fact that argument is useless and each time you have to return the next token" 
I don't really get this part, if I pass 1 as the second argument all the times, I just fill my struct with the content of the first field...

Comment: @RafaelaSouza ah yes, sorry, I supposed you do not give _line_ but NULL from the second calls. I edit my answer

Comment: @RafaelaSouza why do you write the read csv file in a binary file, what is the interest ?

Comment: Actually I have a lot more to do, but I was really stuck on that part, thank you!