# Improper Binary File Read

Tags: c

I am new to C and am trying to read and write structures to a .dat file. When I add the data, I see the characters in the .dat file. However, I am unable to read the data and my code outputs nothing when it should output "val" for every occurrence of a structure.

I have looked at numerous sources but I cannot find how my code differs to those.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/readwrite-structure-file-c/ 
This website was used to initially understand how to do this.

[Read/Write to binary files in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598572/read-write-to-binary-files-in-c)
I used this to see how my code could be fixed but the solution did not help.

I tried changing the statement in the while loop.

```
struct person
{
    int id;
    char lastName[15];
    char firstName[15];
    char age[4];
};


int main(void) {
  //create new file
  FILE *fp = fopen("file.dat", "wb+");

  struct person a = {10, "Smith", "John", 25};
  fwrite(&a, sizeof(a), 1, fp);

  struct person b = {2, "Ali", "Jon", 12};
  fwrite(&b, sizeof(b), 1, fp);

 struct person c = {19, "Walter", "Martha", 82};
  fwrite(&c, sizeof(c), 1, fp);

  struct person p; 
  while(fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, fp))
  printf("val");
}
```

Currently, it should print 3 "Vals" as there are three persons being added to the dat file. However, nothing is being printed out.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: You need to [rewind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind) the file before you can read it back (or [fseek](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are done writing the records, the file pointer (the "cursor", the position you are reading/writing) is at the end of the file. You have to set that position back to the begin of the file by using `rewind()`, `fseek()` or `fsetpos()` before trying to read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read back and print then try to capture the start position of the file before writing the file with `fpos_t` and `fgetpos()` . Later after writing to file set back the initial position using `fsetpos()` and use `fget()` to read the content and print them. Check the modified code as below-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct person
{
    int id;
    char lastName[15];
    char firstName[15];
    char age[4];
};


int main(void) {
  //create new file
  FILE *fp = fopen("file.dat", "wb+");
  fpos_t position;


  struct person a = {10, "Smith", "John", "25"};
  fwrite(&a, sizeof(a), 1, fp);

  struct person b = {2, "Ali", "Jon", "12"};
  fwrite(&b, sizeof(b), 1, fp);

  struct person c = {19, "Walter", "Martha", "82"};
  fwrite(&c, sizeof(c), 1, fp);

  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

  struct person p; 
  while(fread((void *)&p, sizeof(p),1,fp)==1)
  {
    printf("%d\n",p.id);
    printf("%s\n",p.lastName);
    printf("%s\n",p.firstName);
    printf("%s\n",p.age);    
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a few typos in your answer and the description at the beginning doesn't match your code. Also, why do you suggest with your code to read a binary file char-by-char with `fgetc()`?

Comment: @Swordfish. Thanks, corrected the typos. The code is in sync with description- first, get start position using ```fpos_t``` and ```fgetpos()``` later before reading set the position to initial using ```fsetpos()```, as of now modified the statement grammatically to understand well. About ```fgetc()``` its one of the way to read the file, is there any problem or risk in using it?

Comment: *About `fgetc()` its one of the way to read the file, is there any problem or risk in using it?* – Risk? No. But I bet apaul30 wants his structs back and not chars. And as the structs contain arrays of char, there is also a good chance that there are strings in the data written to the file, but also garbage after a string when the string doesn't have the exact length of the array.

Comment: Okay got it. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Swordfish modified the code to remove ```fgetc()```